# How to make background images on the full page?

Tags: html, css

I try to set background image for `body` like as:

```css
body {
        background: url("http://beerhold.it/1024/800") center bottom;
        z-index: 10;
        height: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
}
```

But It displays image only partially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do u use height: 100%. This height based on height of inner content. Not a parrent block.

```css
body {
  background: url("http://beerhold.it/1024/800") center bottom;
  z-index: 10;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

add this as well. by default the height of html is set to auto so body height can't be 100% unless you set the height of html

Comment: It was in my code. when I deleted this my styles had worked

Comment: it works only if you use `height: 100vh` instead of `height: 100%` in `body`

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your code

```css
background: url("http://3ksks.com/pic.jpg");
background-size: 100% auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
  background: url("http://beerhold.it/1024/800") center bottom;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```